# Site display problems when zooming in the browser

Tags: html, css, scale

I got a problem on a website http://madamrimma.by/, when browser scale is less then 100%, the website is displaying incorrect: http://joxi.ru/qlrGUhjKTJBMAUGBReA. This website is not created by me and i don't understand how it happened.

Comment: It does not break on my side when resizing the browser. From the screenshot, it seems that the css is not loading. Try CTRL+ F5 when the browser is resized.

Comment: it looks like the bug appears on a different browser resolutions (1920×1080)

Answer (score 2):

This is because downscaling the browser actually increases the width of the page in pixels. While the browser may occupy say, 1024px, when the page is downscaled, the number of pixels as represented in the DOM is actually more than 1024px.

Additionally, there are media queries that control the appearance of the page. If you look at `#wrappen`, the following CSS exists:

```
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1025px)
#wrappen {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f25aeb;
    background: #fff;
}
```

When you downscale your browser, the number of pixels as represented in the DOM is more than 1920px. Hence, the fixed-width layout imposed by `#wrappen` is ignored, and the layout breaks.

If you have an extremely high-resolution monitor, you can also resize your browser window beyond 1920 pixels and have the same effect.

### The Fix

The fix for this is easy. Simply remove the offending `max-width` media query. Of course, this is not optimal for high resolution screens, as most space is wasted, but at least the layout does not break.

[image: Removed Media Query]

[image: Resultant Page]

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is having fixed widths to the div elements in the code. Change them to %'s so that it will be fixed. Every element should be center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I use this media quires:

```
/* Mobile styles go first, without media 
queries. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
/* Larger mobile styles (wider than 320 
pixels) */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* Tablet styles (wider than 600 pixels) 
*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
/* Large laptop styles (wider than 1024 
pixels) */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
/* Desktop styles (wider than 1140 
pixels) */
}
```

for each resolutions and it works.